# Manage cache images with AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, iphone, caching, afnetworking

I load some images to my app with AFNetworking 2.0. By default it cached it. I do not want to load images always from the cache. I want to load the image from the cache only if the web image and the cached image are not the same. So how can I do it?

My code:

```
  AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
  requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
 [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
_imageView.image = responseObject;

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
 }];
 [requestOperation start];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to handle caching is to modify your server's `cache-control` headers to describe for how long the client should cache a given resource for.  The URL foundation loading system will respect the headers provided by the server.

Unless you have a very good reason to disable the built-in caching mechanisms client-side, you shouldn't - it will make your app slower in 99% of cases, since there are many situations where your app may try to get the same resource.

If you need to override them client side, subclass the AFNetworking request serializer(s) used in your app, and set the `cachePolicy` on the NSMutableURLRequests returned by them.  Then assign this request serializer to your request operation manager or session manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `cachePolicy` when creating the `NSURLRequest`.

```
+ (id)requestWithURL:(NSURL *)theURL 
         cachePolicy:(NSURLRequestCachePolicy)cachePolicy 
     timeoutInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeoutInterval
```

Value of the cachePolicy should be NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy.

> **NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy**
>
> Specifies that the caching logic defined in the protocol
>   implementation, if any, is used for a particular URL load request.
>   This is the default policy for URL load requests.

You should also make sure the response contains the `Cache-Control` `HTTP` header. This header must be present in the response from the server to enable `HTTP` caching by a client.

If you still get the cached image this means that the server simply tells you in `Cache-Control` `HTTP` header to use cache. This should be easy to change on the server side. However, sometimes you don't have access to the server. In this case you can fallback to using `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` which will ignore your cached data and download the fresh image.

Comment: Thanks, How can I test AFNetworking 2.0 to cache load or to download?

Comment: Just change the image on the server side and see if `AFNetworking` downloads it or uses the cached one.